# GraphViz - org.graphstream.graph.IdAlreadyInUseException

Tags: java, graphviz

I use GraphViz to draw oriented graph - I read file with graph data according to http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Reading-files-using-FileSource/ tutorial.

Everything works fine when there is not two or more edges between two nodes. If so, the *org.graphstream.graph.IdAlreadyInUseException: singleton exception: id "(48;63)" already in use. Cannot create an edge.* is thrown.

I understand the exeption quite well. The problem is that I don't know how to get rid of it (and I don't want to write my own data parser).

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about graphviz, but the error you get and the tutorial you refer to are GraphStream related.

In GraphStream, you need to use the `MultiGraph` class in place of the `DefaultGraph` one.

Comment: I tried that, however the exception was thrown anyway. My solution was identifying parallel edges while processing the file parsing. I added these edges afterwards.